# Python: How to delete a file that is being written onto

Tags: python, api, instagram

I'm using the Instabot API to automate uploading a picture every hour, that all works fine. The problem is every time I run the code a config file is created, within that folder there is a 'log.txt' file which is always being written onto while the code is running.

For some reason if I want to run the code again I need to delete the config file, then the code works just fine. But I want to automate this code to repeat every hour.

I've tried the following code to delete the folder once the picture is uploaded but I get the following error:

```
 os.remove(my_file)
```

error

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: (file-name)
```

So my question is how can I delete the config folder, while its been written onto while my code is running.

*.py

```
from instabot import Bot 

def bot():
    bot = Bot() 
    bot.login(username = "######",  
            password = "######") 
    
    bot.upload_photo("QuotePost.jpg", 
                    caption = 'Here is todays quote Hope this helps!') 
                    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot()
```